# Spoon deleted all the files in the Documents directory

Tags: android, macos, spoon

I am using Spoon to run automated tests on Android devices. I have made a shell script that at some point runs the tests through spoon on all the connected devices. 
I configured it so it saves the output in /Users/MyUsername/Documents/ where run_ID is a unix timestamp.

My problem is that, sometimes (4 times until now, in 6 months) it deletes all the files and folders found in Documents directory. I don't know why it does that but it's very frustrating as i have other things saved in there, that shouldn't be deleted by any means. I don't know where to look to change this behaviour so i hope you guys can give me an advice.

This is the error output i got when it tried to delete everything (managed to catch it):

```
2015-08-05 13:54:27 [SR.runTests] Executing instrumentation suite on 7 device(s).
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to clean output directory: /Users/MyUsername/Documents
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.runTests(SpoonRunner.java:132)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.run(SpoonRunner.java:113)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.main(SpoonRunner.java:530)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: /Users/MyUsername/Documents/Framework/Automation/node_modules/scribe-js/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.runTests(SpoonRunner.java:130)
    ... 2 more
```

The shell script that starts spoon looks like this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar /Users/MyUsername/Documents/programmingStuff/spoon-runner-1.1.10-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk /Users/MyUsername/git/hb_android_30/bin/beta.apk --test-apk /Users/MyUsername/Documents/programmingStuff/Regression-git/bin/PROD.apk --sdk /Users/MyUsername/Documents/programmingStuff/android-sdk-macosx --output /Users/MyUsername/Documents/$1 &&
```

where $1 is the run_ID passed from another shell script.

So far, i had backups of everything in Documents folder, but it's annoying to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

i discovered what the problem was. The script didn't got a parameter so $1 was empty and the command deleted all my contents in the Documents folder.